# Apply a property sheet to empty C++ visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, properties

I have created an empty Visual C++ project and add a single `main.cpp` like:

```
#include <mylib.h>

int main() {
     abc();
     return 0;
}
```

Where `abc()` is a function in `mylib` say. To use `mylib` the following settings need pointing to the right locations.

```
Configaration Setting -> VC++ Directories -> Executable Directories 
Configaration Setting -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories 
Configaration Setting -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories 
Configaration Setting -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
```

This is very tedious to do for multiple projects so I'd like to set up a property sheet for these settings. When I add a property sheet to the project the following XML stub is generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

But the property editor is blank for the property sheet?

[image]

I just want an simple solution for adding the needed external library setting to a project?

Comment: How do you open this editor? You should right-click on your main.cpp in the Soulution Explorer and select properties...

Comment: @DaveChandler To open the property editor for the property sheet, right-clicking on a source file is not the way to go.

Comment: @Angew I would like a non/cross-versions dependent solution but I have VS C++ express and VS 10. The editor is access via `view -> other windows -> properties window`.

Comment: @Angew  Ok, but how is it done then? When I add a new CPropertyPage, it is possible to do so.
There also is a "C/C++" entry beyond "Configuration Properties" in the editor.

Comment: Please use View->Property Manager _not_ Properties Window. Then open property pages by double clicking the property file.

Comment: @nabulke That's the correct way. You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to edit the *Property Sheet* please select

**View->Property Manager**

In that view, open the *Property Pages* and edit your settings by double clicking your settings file. Just don't use the *Properties Window*.